# Decorator Pattern in Scala

Tags: scala, decorator

I have the following Code in Scala.
I have a few questions regarding the functionality and syntax.

```
type Logger = String => Unit

type Decorator = Logger => Logger

  val uppercase: Decorator = 
    logger =>
      (msg: String) => logger(msg.toUpperCase)

  val info: Decorator =
    logger =>
      (msg:String) => logger("info " + msg)
```

Did I understand it correctly, that `Decorator` is the input of the `ìnfo` function?

Why is the declaration of the return type not necessary here?

Then I use the code like this:

```
val prefixUppercase = info(uppercase(println(_)))
```

Why can I pass `println(_)` to `uppercase`?

The `uppercase` function requires an argument of the type `Decorator`, which `println()` is clearly not.

Additonally I use `println(_)`, but when I try to pass an named argument like this `println(x)` I get an error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Did I understand it correctly, that `Decorator` is the input of the `ìnfo` function?

```
val info: Decorator =
  logger =>
    (msg:String) => logger("info " + msg)
```

No, `Decorator` is the *type* of `info`.

`info` is declared to be a function from `Logger` to `Logger` (which is what `Decorator` expands to).

```
val info: Decorator =  // info is a Decorator
                       // i.e. a function Logger => Logger

  logger =>            // so this makes logger a Logger
                       // (the input for the Decorator)

                       // what follows is the output of the Decorator
                       // i.e. another Logger
                       // i.e. a function String => Unit

    (msg:String) =>    // so this is that String input to the
                       // resulting (decorated) Logger  


       logger("info " + msg)  // and this is what our decorator does
                              // to the String to be logged:
                              // we prefix it with "info "
                              // and give it to the underlying logger
```

> Why is the declaration of the return type not necessary here?

The return type is being declared (see above).

In general, Scala is quite good at infering types, so you do not actually need to declare the type of `info` if it can be derived from other known types, but

a) it is good practice to declare non-obvious types, especially on public values. This serves as documentation, speeds up compilation and can avoid errors (in case the inferred type is not what you wanted it helps tracking down the problem)

b) in your case, it is also the most straight-forward way to let the compiler know what type `logger` should have here. You would have to declare that somewhere else otherwise.

> Why can I pass `println(_)` to `uppercase`? The uppercase function requires an argument of the type `Decorator`, which `println()` is clearly not.

`uppercase` does not require a `Decorator`, `uppercase` *is* a `Decorator`, meaning it is a function that takes a `Logger` and returns a `Logger`.

So it needs a `Logger`, which is a function that takes a `String` and does not return anything. `println` is such a function, so you can pass it to `uppercase` (as its `Logger` input argument).

> I try to pass an named argument like this `println(x)` I get an error.

What is `x` in this case?

You need to create a `Logger`, meaning a function that takes a String and does not return anything special.

`x => println(x)` will do.

`println(_)` is short-hand for the same thing, and will do.

`println(somethingElse)` or `println(123)` are not functions that take a String anymore (they do not take any arguments anymore) so those are not `Logger`s.

Comment: Great insightful answer. Thank you!